# Shader Storage Buffer Objects: endianness?

Tags: android, opengl-es, bytebuffer

OpenGL ES 3.1, Android.

I have set up SSBO with the intention to write something in fragment shader and read it back in the application. Things almost work, i.e. I can read back the value I have written, with one issue: when I read an INT, its bytes come reversed (a '17' = 0x00000011 written in the shader comes back as '285212672' = 0x11000000 ).

Here's how I do it:

Shader

```
(...)
layout (std140,binding=0) buffer SSBO
  {
  int ssbocount[];
  };
(...)
ssbocount[0] = 17;   
(...)
```

Application code

```
int SIZE = 40;
int[] mSSBO = new int[1];
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
(...)
glGenBuffers(1,mSSBO,0);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, mSSBO[0]);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, SIZE, null, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
buf = (ByteBuffer) glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, SIZE, GL_MAP_READ_BIT );
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,0, mSSBO[0]);
(...)
int readValue = buf.getInt(0);
```

Now print out the Value and it comes as '17' with reversed bytes.
Notice I DO allocate the ByteBuffer with 'nativeOrder'. Of course, I could manually flip the bytes, but the concern is this would only sometimes work, depending on the endianness of the host machine...

Comment: What's even more strange, when I replace the 'ByteOrder.nativeOrder()' with 'ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN' or 'ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN' - I am still getting the int flipped. The ByteOrder appears to have no effect...

Comment: If you use native endianess, and create an integer view of it using `ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer()` does it work?

Comment: Yes, then it works. Thanks. Quite surprising that I have to create an integer view for the ByteOrder to work!

Comment: Yep, I agree ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to use native endianess, and create an integer view of the `ByteBuffer` using `ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer()`. For some reason the local `getInt()` calls do not seem to respect the local `ByteBuffer` endianness settings.